# View with multiple models only POST 1 model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is the model I'm using for a view

```
public class MainRegisterViewModel
{
    public RegisterViewModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
    public RegisterFormValuesViewModel RegisterValues { get; set; }
}
```

`RegisterFormValuesViewModel` contains all the values for the controls (list of countries, states and stuff like that) and  `RegisterViewModel` contains the information for a user.

Then I load the controls like this.

```
@model ProjetX.Models.MainRegisterViewModel
@{  
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> countries = Model.RegisterValues.Countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = x.Country,
        Value = x.Id.ToString()
    });

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> states = Model.RegisterValues.States.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = x.State,
        Value = x.Id.ToString()
    });
}

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {

               ....

                <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Country, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                     <div class="col-md-10">
                          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Country, countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
                     </div>
               </div>

                ....
```

Also the Register function takes a `MainRegisterViewModel` as parameter.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(MainRegisterViewModel model)
```

The problem is when I submit the form, `RegisterFormValuesViewModel` is `NULL`.

Any ideas why?

Thank you

**Context**

I'm doing this because I load the `RegisterFormValuesViewModel` from an API and I'm trying to call it only once. The problem was when a user POST a form with errors and you return the view back, I had to call the API again to get `RegisterFormValuesViewModel`.

Before this it was only one model and a viewbag for `RegisterFormValuesViewModel` but I had to call the API every time the form was loaded because the viewbag wasn't posted. That's why I thought I could use 2 models and POST them both.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but unless `RegisterFormValuesViewModel`'s values are in the POST, the model won't be repopulated. For example, the selected value of the `states` dropdown list will be in the request, but the items used to build the list will not.

Comment: Is there a simple way to POST the values?

Comment: Joe's answer gives some options. Hidden fields are the easiest, but you want to be sure you aren't creating a giant request (like webforms viewstate did). For things like states/countries that don't change often, you could put them into a cache instead.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be considered a giant request if the form has overall 100 checkboxes. RegisterViewModel contains some lists of 20-30 booleans? Is there any best practices for this. Should I split the form in different steps?

Comment: There's no rule for when the request is too big, but one thing to consider is how often you are moving the data, i.e. are you posting it once when the form is done, or over and over? From what you described, the request would be bigger than my personal preference but *probably* wouldn't cause an issue, when used sparingly. You might be able to improve things by using AJAX in that you could build the page once but submit as many async POSTs as you wanted.

Comment: Regarding the 100 checkboxes, I would typically split those up into multiple tabs/screens, or at least organize them into groups. The best solution really depends on the type of application. You might find more ideas (or ask the question) at http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah the UI is split into different steps but they are all in the same form and there's only one submit. The UI is not a problem but I will have to optimize the request. Thank you! I will upvote one of your answers for your great help.

Comment: @TimMedora Would you still use a model for RegisterFormValuesViewModel  if you use cache instead of posting the data back to the server? I find it weird to see it null when I post the form but at the same time I don't really like to use viewbag.

Comment: You could access the cached values directly from the view, but it is arguably cleaner/more testable/more reusable to put those values into the view model. A view model should provide the view with all the data it needs to do its job. I find it helps to mentally and/or literally split the view model into "properties that help build the page" and "properties that come from user input".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the values of `RegisterFormValuesViewModel` to be posted, they need to included in the form or other location that the ModelBinder looks for values.  The (default) model binder will pick up values from the action params, Request.Form, route data, and Request.QueryString (I think Request.Files is included too).

If your `RegisterFormValuesViewModel` is expensive to create, you can add it's values as hidden fields that are posted with the form or implement a custom `ValueProviderFactory` that works with application or session state.